# Do You Need Backlinks to Rank for Long Tail Keywords?

Tags: google-search, keywords

My site has been known to Google for about 9 months now, the domain is around 3 years old.

I have a generous amount of content related to my niche across my site, around 1000 words per page, some up to 4000 word articles. All linked well with a mix of long and exact match terms I want to rank for.

Understandably, I don't rank particularly well for the 2-3 word exact match terms, at best page 3 or 4 of the serps.

But I'm (surprisingly) having a bit of trouble ranking for long tail keywords. Terms 5 + words in length.

"Franchises for Sale in Princetown" , Google returns a result set of about 4 pages, and it ignores completely the word "Princetown". I'm not even in the results  unless I put Princetown in quotes.

Instead Google would rather show rubbishy results about commercial properties than my page which has text, headings etc all containing my keywords (not stuffed).

I'm finding a bit of a paradox here.

Some say you're supposed to get organic traffic to help rank.
But how do you rank (even for long tail terms) without Backlinks?
And how are you supposed to get Backlinks when you don't rank anywhere?

What would you chaps suggest is the biggest thing to prioritise to get my long tail keywords off the ground?

Like

- franchises for sale in Princetown
- top franchises for sale in the UK

Is it just a case of internally linking on these (and variations of) these phrases at such an early point in the domain's life? Or should I buy guest posts?

I use ahrefs and semrush and can't see any major SEO problems.